# Access to session vars and GET vars after AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, variables

After an AJAX call, I don't manage to use my "old" var (PHP ones, GET ones)...

For instance (case of adding an event) :

```
function addEvent() {
    var formEvent=new Object;

    $("#formEvent input, #formEvent select").each(function () {
        if(!$(this).is(":disabled")) {
            formEvent[$(this).attr("name")]=$(this).val();
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url : "/function/php/event/addEvent.php", 
        data : {
            "dataEvent" : formEvent
        },
        dataType : "text", 
        type : "POST", 
        success : function(data) {
            modal("Inscription", data);
            eval($(data).text());
        }
    });
}
```

I'd like to access to session vars and GET params (name of the user) in my addEvent.php page.

Do you have any idea ? 
Is it due to ajax settings ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you post the `addEvent.php` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access get params, you'll need to set `type : "GET",` in your ajax call and you'll be able to get them normally (`$_GET['VARIABLENAME']`)

For the session vars, you'll need a `session_start()` in your addEvent.php.

**EDIT :**

To pass your data if you use jQuery, you could use something like

```
data: formEvent.serialize(),
```

Comment: Actually he doesnt have to use `type: 'GET'` - he can just encode them directly on the URL, like `url: '/function/php/event/addEvent.php?VARIABLENAME=thevalue',` and then still use POST.